# Is there any in-built way to implement change notification of between 2 objects other than events and delegates?

Tags: c#

I have 2 class, say Class A with some properties and Class B with some properties. If a property in Class A is modified, I want to update a property in Class B and also I want to update the result to other property in Class A again.

Is there any way to do it without using Events?

Comment: Events are probably your best bet.

Comment: Just to clarify "event and delegates" you mean regula `INotifyPreopertyChanged` interface, right?

Comment: It may help if you explain what *problems* you perceive with using events/delegates such that you need a replacement. Because what if someone makes a suggestion that shares the same problems? You're no further forward, and then we have to *guess* at something that you *know*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediator pattern. This isn't production ready (obviously):

```
public interface IMessage { }

public class TestMessage: IMessage { public string Test {get;set;} }

public interface IMediator
{
    void Subscribe(ISubscriber subscriber);
    void Send(IMessage message);
}

public interface ISubscriber { 
    void Notify(IMessage message);
}

public class ConcreteMediator : IMediator
{
    private List<ISubscriber> _subscribers = new List<ISubscriber>();

    public void Subscribe(ISubscriber subscriber)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
    }

    public void Send(IMessage message)
    {
         var copy = new List<ISubscriber>(_subscribers);
         foreach(var sub in copy)
            sub.Notify(message);
    }
}
```

Full running sample [here](https://rextester.com/DXGO20214).

I would advise you to use generics instead of checking type of message inside `Notify`, but I don't want to post too much code.

In your example both classes would be subscribers and they would post messages inside property's setter.

My solution isn't thread-safe and it doesn't check if a subscriber has already subscribed. This is something that can be handled many ways and I leave it to the implementer.